# Reference for principles regarding construction of geometric figures with fewest steps as possible.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Is there such guiding principle? I have played geometry construction games, and most of the time I do too many steps making it hard to proceed.

Comment: I have the same problem but I guess it is just experience and trying out :)